# Beautifulsoup error with class content Hyphens "-"?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am used python 2.7 + BeautifulSoup 4.4.1

```
e = BeautifulSoup(data)
s1 = e.find("div", class_="one").get_text() # Successful
s2 = e.find("div", class_="two-three").get_text() # ERROR
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It error with class content Hyphens :(

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: What doesn't work? Could you add the error you are getting with the stacktrace?

Comment: I successfully used the same as you, but it errow now :(

`... s2 = e.find("div", attrs={'class': "two-three"}).get_text()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'`

Comment: It means that there is no such element with class `two-three` in your data.

Comment: There exist "two-three" elements.
I have many similar problems with classes containing "-"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110097/discussion-between-user2661319-and-aks).

Comment: My Console: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-5hIaEdsBK3c/Vx213v-5dNI/AAAAAAACvHc/djNVxDALY-Qo7Fd0EeGmOgfaAMK6jt8GwCLcB/s0/py.png

Test site: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zing.zalo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with bs4 or hyphens, the problem is that without a user-agent you get different source returned, using requests below we get what you want:

```
In [26]: import requests

In [27]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [28]: r = requests.get("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zing.zalo", 
                         headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36"})

In [29]: soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

In [30]: print(soup.select("span.rating-count"))
[<span aria-label="573,575 ratings" class="rating-count">573,575</span>]
```

If we run it without a user-agent:

```
In [31]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [32]: r = requests.get("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zing.zalo")

In [33]: soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

In [34]: print(soup.select("span.rating-count"))
[]
```

If you printed the source from each request you will see they are very different.

Answer (score 1):

After, looking at your screenshot in the comments:

First of all you need to read the response, you cannot directly cast what you get to `str`:

```
e = e.read()
```

Second, it seems that some of the content is being populated using javascript hence your html doesn't contain those tags.

i.e. There are no elements present with class `rating-count`:

```
>>> s.find('span', class_='rating-count')
[]
```

It doesn't mean that hyphenated search for the class name is not working because if you try `display-price` it would work:

```
>>> s.find('span', class_='display-price')
 <span class="display-price">Free</span>
```

which means the ones you are trying to get aren't available in the HTML like I said earlier in the comments.

Comment: What would be the difference?

Comment: I successfully used the same as you but It not work now :(

Answer (score 0):

Thank AKS and Padraic Cunningham. I did it :)

I checked and found: Before using "User Agent", data reponse not contain "rating-count".

(1) Right:  Before (2) Left: After

[image]